# CAS: credentials don't get validated if the login page is idle

Tags: java, cas, jasig

I have a situation in which, if the login page stays idle for sometime then the entered credentials don't get validated and nothing happens. Instead same login page is displayed clearing the entered `username` and `password`. But next try will work and the credentials get validated. Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: It could be related to session timeout, but the CAS login page should be stateless. Have you modified anything or are you using the CAS spring web flow straight out of the box?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with `<session-timeout>` time period from `web.xml`? I have default time of 5 mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a timeout associated with the CAS login page. When a login page is served to the client, a login ticket associated with it is created which lasts the CAS web session. So you have to enter credentials before the login ticket expires, which depens on the CAS web session timeout (defined in your web.xml).

Comment: How would i extend or shorten the timeout time for login page then?

Comment: change the timeout defined with `<session-timeout>` in your `web.xml`

Comment: I have `<session-timeout>` of time 30 but still the issue exits before the 30 minutes is passed.

Comment: Very strange, it works for me : don't you have some side effect from your application server ? (fro example, in Tomcat, there is one server web.xml defined for the server)

Comment: What will happen if i removed session config from the web.xml ?

Comment: I imagine the global web.xml of the application server is taken into account instead. You need to make the test...